# Is there a way to make a document image vertical from any position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I have documents like this:

[image]

In some cases, the image is rotated to the right, or even upside down.

Document example rotated right:

[image]

Document example rotated upside down:

[image]

Is there a way to make the image vertical, no matter the starting position?

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with typical (rectangular) [paper sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size) and left-to-right directed texts as shown in your examples, the two following assumptions can be made:

- Paper height must be always larger than paper width. That is easy to check. If needed, rotate by 90 degrees.
- More text will be found on the left side than on the right side. Therefore, sum pixel values over all rows. The summed value in the left area of the document must be larger than the summed value in the right area. If needed, rotate by 180 degrees.

Here's the code I used:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io              # Only needed for web grabbing images; for local images, use cv2.imread(...)

def correct_orientation(img):

    print('\nImage:\n------')

    h, w = img.shape
    if (w > h):
        img = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
        h, w = img.shape
        print('\nRotated 90 degrees')

    summed = np.sum(255-img, axis=0)

    if (np.sum(summed[30:130]) < np.sum(summed[w-130:w-30])):
        img = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_180)
        print('\nRotated 180 degrees')

    return img

correct_1 = io.imread('https://i.imgur.com/Gu8uAp6.jpg', as_gray=True)
rot_90 = io.imread('https://i.imgur.com/o97vu59.jpg', as_gray=True)
rot_180 = io.imread('https://i.imgur.com/XkBNfEb.jpg', as_gray=True)
correct_2 = io.imread('https://i.imgur.com/EvaioRS.jpg', as_gray=True)

images = [correct_orientation(img) for img in [correct_1, rot_90, rot_180, correct_2]]
```

The output for the given images:

```
Image:
------

Image:
------

Rotated 90 degrees

Rotated 180 degrees

Image:
------

Rotated 180 degrees

Image:
------
```

In your images, the documents have additional borders (blue or black). That makes finding the lines' beginning and ending difficult. So, adjusting the manual set values for the left and right area should be adapted in a final solution.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** Forgot the following visualizations. For the correctly oriented document, the summed values over all rows look like this:

[image: Correct]

See the larger values on the left side, these are the lines' beginnings.

The same for the 180 degree rotated document looks like this:

[image: Not correct]

Again, notice the "artifacts" on the border due to the additional image borders.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are falling foul of EXIF's ability to store an orientation, which some viewers ignore. The easiest thing to do is use **ImageMagick**, which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. Using this command in Terminal, or Command Prompt on Windows, will firstly correct the orientation, then remove the setting so as not to confuse viewers:

```
magick input.jpg -auto-orient -strip result.jpg
```

If using, v6 ImageMagick, replace `magick` with `convert`.

---

Failing that, you could iterate through the four possible orientations by rotating the image each time through 90 degrees. At each orientation, run the image through `pytesseract` and select the orientation that yields most matches with `/usr/share/dict/words.txt` or whatever it is called on your system. For added fun and performance, make the test into a function and call it in parallel on 4 separate threads - one per orientation.

That might look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import cv2
import re
from textblob import TextBlob

def analyse(im, rotation):
   text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config="--psm 4")
   correctedText = TextBlob(text).correct()
   legit = []
   for found in correctedText.split():
      if found in words:
          legit.append(found)
   print(f"Rotation: {rotation}, word count: {len(legit)}, words: {legit}")

# Load dictionary of permissible words
words = set()
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Don't add short words like "at", tesseract often finds small, easily matched strings
        if len(line) > 5:
            words.add(line.rstrip())

# Load document
orig = cv2.imread('document.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = orig.shape
centre = (w//2, h//2)

# Iterate through orientations

# Original, no rotation
r = 0
cv2.imwrite(f'rotated-{r}.png',orig)
analyse(orig,0)

# 90 degrees
r = 90
rotated = cv2.rotate(orig, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE) 
cv2.imwrite(f'rotated-{r}.png',rotated)
analyse(rotated,r)

# 180 degrees
r = 180
rotated = cv2.rotate(orig, cv2.ROTATE_180) 
cv2.imwrite(f'rotated-{r}.png',rotated)
analyse(rotated,r)

# 270 degrees
r = 270
rotated = cv2.rotate(orig, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE) 
cv2.imwrite(f'rotated-{r}.png',rotated)
analyse(rotated,r)
```

**Sample Output**

```
Rotation: 0, word count: 43, words: ['between', 'Secession', 'deserted', 'above', 'noted', 'hereby', 'release', 'other', 'money', 'above', 'together', 'action', 'party', 'against', 'other', 'patty', 'holding', 'depart', 'Canada', 'refund', 'cashier', 'cheque', 'shall', 'their', 'irrevocable', 'author', 'hereby', 'commission', 'regeneration', 'above', 'except', 'hereinbefore', 'shall', 'binding', 'whereof', 'hereunto', 'presence', 'whereof', 'hereunto', 'presence', 'whereof', 'hereunto', 'presence']

Rotation: 90, word count: 0, words: []

Rotation: 180, word count: 10, words: ['saliva', 'sense', 'sleeping', 'anode', 'alone', 'sappy', 'sleeping', 'young', 'sawing', 'Utopian']

Rotation: 270, word count: 0, words: []
```

As you can see, it found far more words with the first, unrotated image.

**Keywords**: Python, tesseract, pytesseract, OCR, psm, config, image, image processing, orientation, auto-orient, auto-orientation.

Comment: I have tried to use this, but as said, i need orientation meta data which I done have for all my documents. ty, I upvoted.
any others?

Comment: I have added a new idea... please have another look.

Comment: **AMAZING** answer, worked for me aswell. abit time consuming but works